# IIS 7.5 performance issue using php

Tags: php, performance, iis

For testing purposes I have the following script in PHP 5.4:

```
define(START_TIME_CUSTOM, microtime(true));
function onEndTimeCompute() {
    $timeTaken = microtime(true) - START_TIME_CUSTOM;
    echo "Completed In: ".number_format($timeTaken, 4)." Seconds\n";
}
register_shutdown_function('onEndTimeCompute');

echo "Just before exit";
exit;
echo "Just after exit";
```

(Script taken from here: https://serverfault.com/questions/192211/iis-logging-write-to-log-file-more-often)
The execute time is: 0.00002 seconds.

I'm running on a local webserver IIS7.5.
I'm also using Chrome.

It takes 1 second to load the page. Any ideas on why it takes a full second? I'd expect it to serve the response instantly.

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're running PHP as a fastCGI module the lag time is like because IIS has to fire up a PHP process from scratch, ie: load the executable, parse the config, load extensions, etc. On the other hand fCGI keeps X processes up and ready to handle requests as soon as they come in.

[There's documentation on fCGI setup here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis).